# Sublime behavior like in VS

Tags: visual-studio, editor, sublimetext, editing

How to do same behaving in Sublime Text as in Visual Studio, when using column selection
for example if there is a line break in a text, the cursor in Sublime go to beginning of a line

[image]

And this is behavior in Visual Studio desired behavior

[image]

Thanks

Comment: You know you can indent and dedent blocks of text by selecting them and hitting `Ctrl-[` or `Ctrl-]`, right? You don't need to do multiple selections at all...

Comment: +1 to @MattDMo. That's the correct way of doing it. You can also use Shift+Tab to dedent by tabs, or add a tab to every line of the selected text just by pressing tab.

Comment: @sergioFC I turned my comment into an answer below, expanding on it quite a bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you may want this functionality for other reasons, it seems like you are using it to adjust the indentation of code blocks. Fortunately, there is a much easier way of doing this. Select the text for which you want to change the indentation, then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>]</kbd> to increase the indentation (move block right), or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>[</kbd> to decrease indentation (move block left). You can also increase indentation by selecting the desired lines and hitting <kbd>Tab</kbd>, and using <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd> to decrease it. The one place I can think of where multiple selections would come in handy is if, for some reason, you need to indent/dedent by fewer spaces than are in your tab stop. For example, if I have some code that's indented 3 spaces, and I want to change it to 4 (using the **`Indent Using Spaces`** setting in the **`View -> Indentation`** menu), I would use a multiple selection to put a cursor on each line, then use <kbd>Space</kbd> or <kbd>Backspace</kbd> to adjust spacing appropriately.